# Class attributes don't have the same value depending on where they're accessed (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import

It seems depending on where they're accessed from, class attributes don't have the same value. I don't understand why that's the case, and any help in understanding this or working around it would be welcome.

Consider the following .py files :

foo.py:

```
from bar import *


class Foo:
    someAttribute = None

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, value):
        cls.someAttribute = value


def main():
    Foo.update("some value")
    print(Foo.someAttribute)
    bar = Bar()
    bar.showStuff()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and bar.py:

```
from foo import *


class Bar:

    def showStuff(self):
        print(Foo.someAttribute)
```

One would expect and intend the output to be "some value" for both `print` instructions. Yet my output is the following :

```
$ python foo.py
some value
None
```

Comment: Does this actually run? each of your files is trying to import the other

Comment: This does run, and import cycles shouldn't be a problem, how else would two classes reference each other?

Comment: @khelwood: yes, it runs just fine, because there are **three** modules here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Mysterious ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have **two copies** of the `foo` module in memory. One is called `__main__`, the other is called `foo`. That's because you run `foo` as a script, which is then stored as the `__main__` module.

So when you run `python foo.py` the following happens:

- `sys.modules['__main__']` is created to hold your script namespace.
- `from bar import *` is run

  - `sys.modules['bar']` is created to hold the `bar` module namespace.
  - `from foo import *` is run

    - `sys.modules['foo']` is created to hold the `foo` module namespace.
    - `from bar import *` is run, the `sys.modules['bar']` object is found.
    - No names exist in the empty `sys.modules['bar']` module, *nothing is imported*
    - the `Foo` class and the `main` function are added to the `foo` module.
    - the `if __name__ == '__main__'` is skipped, this is the `foo` module.
  - The names `Foo` and `main` are added to the `bar` namespace
  - The `Bar` class is added to the `bar` namespace
- The names `Foo`, `main` and `Bar` are added to the `__main__` namespace
- New objects `Foo` and `main` are created in the `__main__` namespace.
- The `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is executed and `main()` is called.

Either import from `__main__` in `bar`, or use a *third* python file to be the main script.

Note that if you use `from __main__ import *`, then you *do* have a circular import problem. That's because the `from __main__ import *` won't include anything that has not yet been executed when the `from foo import *` line runs, see the above break-down.

Comment: Splitting foo.py into main.py and foo.py works perfectly, thank you.